# Какая будет лучше регистрация

Tags: ajax, php

Какая будет лучше регистрация и красивее (Для пользователей).  С ajax делать всё без перенаправлений. Или же в виде index.php(вводит данные)->reg.php(регистрируемся)->index.php(кидаем обратно с ответом от reg.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от реализации. Если вы можете сделать перенаправления так, чтобы конечный пользователь не заметил (не испытывал неудобств), то все хорошо.

**UPD:** для пользователей, кстати, любая регистрация не очень хороша.

Comment: секундное не удобство. Там только сохранить данные в БД

Comment: Я не силён в работе с ajax, но и с перенаправлениями позориться что то не хочется. Или юзверям все равно. А вот FaceBook у них ajax?(но ajax вроде появился после создания FB)

Answer (score 0):

Чем меньше переходов и телодвижений для пользователя - тем лучше.
Оптимально для пользователя: на ajax, с минимумом полей и авторизовывать сразу после регистрации.

Comment: Ну сразу авторизация не получится у меня ещё подтверждение Email

Comment: Ну ты спросил какая регистрация будет красивее для пользователей, без особых подробностей :)

В любом случае без перенаправлений предпочтительнее. 
И если, например, нужно чтобы только авторизованные пользователи могли оставлять комментарий, то предпочтительнее вообще во всплывающем окне предлагать посетителю зарегистрироваться, и не отправлять его никуда с той страницы где он коммент пытался оставить.

Comment: А если нужно подтверждение мыла, то тогда авторизовывать сразу при подтверждении.
Главное грамотно всё продумать с кодами подтверждения, чтобы максимально защитить пользователя. :)